# Creating a plan for my database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Summary:
I'm making an SQLite database and want to make sure my plan is possible, and makes sense.

I have been learning about databases for the past few days, and I feel that I am almost ready to start making an SQLite database for my android application. Unfortunately, I'm finding hard to figure out if my plan for organizing my data is the best method available to me. It will be a fairly large undertaking, so I want to make sure all my i's are dotted. If someone can see a more straightforward way of approaching this, I would like that feedback!

Background info:
I need to store data for an unknown number of player characters. These characters will have stats for things like ability scores, skills, as well as their own inventories. Most of these, if not all are multi part. For instance, player strength is calculated from several other sub pieces of data of data, and items have their own stats like cost, durability, etc.

Plan:
I will have one 'character' database. There will be multiple tables. One will be for simple information like name and age, and will have one row per character. The other tables will represent the complex pieces. Each row will have an id (unique to a character, not to  row ) that I will use to represent the character that owns it. That way I can group or retrieve information based on whichever character is active based on the given id.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Juhana My question would be: Does this make sense to do? I have no exprience with this and the project is large, so I would like to make sure what I'm trying is possible/sensical to someone with experience.

Comment: What you are describing above is partial requirements for an application. In this day and age everything, at least almost everything, can be done. The question is who can do it? If you have no experience in database design, and you have a serious project, use a professional. Database design for major projects are beyond simple question and answer.